#  pass PHP variable value to jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This code is not working properly. What i want is just send the variable `$something` to the `page.php`

What is the correct way to do this ? :     `data: <? php $something; ?>,`

**script**

```
$something = "text";

    $.ajax({
    url: "page.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "html",
    data: <? php $something; ?>, 
    success: function (data) {
        $('#total').load('xxx.php');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

myFile.php:

```
<?php $something = 'text'; ?>

<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "html",
  data: '<?php echo $something; ?>', 
  success: function (data) {
    $('#total').load('xxx.php');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is the output:  text is not defined. Probably, you have correct my code, but my code is wrong for this specific purpose . I need to send the variable, but i am not sure about my script. Normally when we submit a form, something like this    `$("#customForm").submit(function() {` works, but in my case,is an isolated variable

Comment: @loops: Clive corrected your code, but what you forgot to do is to apply the corrections. The output you have given is the output of the code without Clive's corrections. Just make sure you enclose the part after `data:` in single quotes (`'`) and give us the output. Plus, I understand `$something = "text";` is PHP part?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you have mistakenly mixed PHP and JavaScript. In your code the line:

```
$something = "text";
```

may be understood in two ways. If this is the whole code you have, then you are actually initializing **JavaScript variable** called `$something`. Later in the code you are trying to use the value of **PHP variable** called `$something`.

What you need to do is to change the code into (assuming you want to pass variable from PHP):

```
<?php $something = "text"; ?>

$.ajax({
url: 'page.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'html',
data: '<? php $something; ?>', 
success: function (data) {
    $('#total').load('xxx.php');
}
});
```

or into (assuming you want JS variable):

```
var $something = 'text';

$.ajax({
url: 'page.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'html',
data: $something, 
success: function (data) {
    $('#total').load('xxx.php');
}
});
```